# How to use Combine collect method after a map

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to use the `collect` method of Combine to split an array of objects into Array of multiples Arrays which would correspond to Rows in a Collection View (eg: `[Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]` would become `[[Item, Item, Item], [Item, Item]]` and so on)

My data is coming from two publisher that I'm chaining to merge my data into a single type consumed by my view.

Here is my code :

```
APIClient().send(APIEndpoints.searchMovies(for: text)).flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<APIResponseList<TVShow>, Error> in
            movies = response.results.map { SearchItemViewModel(movie: $0)}
            return APIClient().send(APIEndpoints.searchTVShows(for: text))
        }
        .map { response -> [SearchItemViewModel] in
            tvShows = response.results.map { SearchItemViewModel(tvShow: $0)}
            let concatItems = tvShows + movies
            return concatItems.sorted { $0.popularity > $1.popularity }
        }
        .collect(3)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .failure:
                self.state = .error
                self.items = []
            case .finished:
                break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { (response) in
            self.state = .data
            self.items = response
        })
            .store(in: &disposables)
```

My problem currently is that inside my `sink` `receiveValue` closure, the `response` parameter doesn't equal the expected result, it just group all my items into an array like this : `[Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]` -> `[[Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]]`
It seems that the `collect` method is not working as expected, any idea about how I could fix this ?

Comment: The reason why collect() doesn't work as expected is that previous section returns only 1 item, which is an array `[Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]`. Do you always have 5 items which you want to transform into the `[[Item, Item, Item], [Item, Item]]`? Or are there any dynamic requirements?

Comment: Hm I see, no it's not always about 5 items, both my arrays (movies and tvShows) are fetched from an API (TMDb API) so each of these contains X elements. Not sure how I could get my expected result.

Comment: it is definitely doable as long as you can clearly define a rule on how you want to split X items into two arrays. Is it 3 in first, and X-3 in second? Or is it round(X/2) in first and X-round(X/2) in the second?

Comment: Nah, I just would like to group my items by 3, and if the number of items isn't a multiple of 3 the last array (group) would contains 2 or 1 items

Comment: So, you want to have multiple arrays each containing 3 or fewer elements?

Comment: Exactly, containing the result of my current `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it just group all my items into an array like this : `[Item, Item, Item, Item, Item]`

Pass that through a `flatMap` and generate its Sequence publisher. Now the Item objects will arrive one at a time and `collect(3)` will work as you expect.

Example:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let head = Just([1,2,3,4,5]) // this is the same as your `.map`
head
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .collect(3)
    .sink{print($0)} // prove that it works: [1, 2, 3], then [4, 5]
    .store(in: &storage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this extension:

```
extension Array {
    func split(numItems:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        var i = 0
        var ret = [[Element]]()
        var current = [Element]()
        while i < self.count {
            current.append(self[i])
            i += 1
            if i % numItems == 0 {
                ret.append(current)
                current = []
            }
        }
        if current.count > 0 {
            ret.append(current)
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to do this:

```
APIClient().send(APIEndpoints.searchMovies(for: text)).flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<APIResponseList<TVShow>, Error> in
            movies = response.results.map { SearchItemViewModel(movie: $0)}
            return APIClient().send(APIEndpoints.searchTVShows(for: text))
        }
        .map { response -> [SearchItemViewModel] in
            tvShows = response.results.map { SearchItemViewModel(tvShow: $0)}
            let concatItems = tvShows + movies
            var sorted =  concatItems.sorted { $0.popularity > $1.popularity }
            return sorted.split(numItems:3)
        }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .failure:
                self.state = .error
                self.items = []
            case .finished:
                break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { (response) in
            self.state = .data
            self.items = response
        })
            .store(in: &disposables)
```